# What IronPython IDE should I use?

Tags: ide, ironpython

This question probably looks a lot like [IDE for ironpython on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755883/ide-for-ironpython-on-windows) question here on stackoverflow.  But I read the answers on that question I still have no idea what IDE I should use.  What I'm looking for is to know pros and cons of a specific IDE.

I recently started learning IronPython.  The only IDE I used so far is [IronPython Studio](http://ironpythonstudio.codeplex.com/) that integrates with Visual Studio.  It was a logical choice for me because I use Visual Studio when I work with C#.

One of the problem I have with IronPython Studio is that I cannot change the default colors.  I have a dark gray background color and black Python code doesn't look very good on that background.  I looked in Environment->Fonts and Colors in Option dialog but couldn't find the option to change IronPython colors.  Let it be my side question:
How to change default colors in integrated IronPython Studio?

I heard about SharpDevelop but I don't know if it's going to be a big improvement of IronPython Studio.  I decided to ask you before I'll try it.

So please could you please let me know of pros and cons of your favorite IronPython IDE.  Don't tell me "I use XYZ IDE and love it".  I want to know why you love it and what it's missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Michael Foord has compared different IDEs for IronPython. You can find it [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/tools-and-ides.shtml).

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time I use Scite for my IronPython scripting -- since I'm normally using it as a scripting language for build process rather than anything else, one page of syntax highlighting is usually enough.

As a general purpose Python IDE I use NetBeans Python EA, which treats CPython, Jython and IronPython pretty much as equals, so I can just set it to the platform I want to use today, and everything else remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I also expect that I'm going to use IronPython as my scripting language.  I would love to avoid to use two different editors; one for C# and another one for python scripts.  I've never heard of Scite before and I'm definitely is going to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You now have a good Visual studio 2010 integration with [IronPython Tools](http://ironpython.net/tools/).