# IronPython studio cannot change default font colors

Tags: ide, ironpython, ironpython-studio

I cannot figure out how to change the default colors in Visual Studio for python files. I have a dark gray background color and black Python code doesn't look very good on that background. I looked in Environment->Fonts and Colors in Option dialog but couldn't find the option to change IronPython colors.

This question was a sub question in my stackoverflow [question about IronPython IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417747/what-ironpython-ide-should-i-use) but I never got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Environment-> Fonts and Colors, under "Text Editor" won't changing the "Plain Text" to whatever foreground color you want, work?

Comment: I wish it was that simple.  It doesn't work for me.  Plus I don't want to mess up my C# fonts.