# Compiling an IronPython WPF project to exe: Missing dlls

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio-2010, ironpython

I want to compile my IronPython WPF based app into a .exe file. I looked up the net for solutions and found this on SO:

[Compiling an IronPython WPF project to exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999489/compiling-an-ironpython-wpf-project-to-exe).

I found [this modified pyc.py file](http://pastebin.com/FgXbZY29) better than the original as I do not have to pass the names of all the files in the project to pyc at the command line. When I run this, I get a dll and an executable. I also included the other dll files mentioned on the above discussion, like IronPython.dll. There is only one problem. I have the following at the top of my main file code:

```
import wpf

from System.Windows import MessageBox, Application, Window
```

The app runs fine on VS2010 but the executable seems not to be able to find any dll named wpf or Window. I have this file called IronPython.Wpf.dll which I included in the folder but that does not seem to work. What dll am I missing here? Or is there any other way I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 4):

You should add

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('IronPython.Wpf')
```

And make sure you put `IronPython.Wpf.dll`, from the IronPython's install directory in the same directory as your main script.

I'm still getting an Exception related with STA Threads, but that's for other question.

**Edit:** Look at [this](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/19409?ProjectName=ironpython) for the STA error