# Server for updates for IronPython in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ironpython

I used guide for using IronPython in Eclipse found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755883/ide-for-ironpython-on-windows) , but I have problem to add server for updates. Does anyone use Eclipse for IronPython and can help me?