# Python vs Iron Python

Tags: python, ironpython

I have to make a GUI for some testing teams. I have been asked to do it in Python, but when I Google, all I see is about Iron Python.

I also was asked not to use Visual Studio because it is too expensive for the company. So if you have any idea to avoid that I would be very happy.

I am still new to Python and programming overall so not any to advanced solutions.

If you have any questions just ask.

*GUI PART: with would you use when using windows and mac(most windows) I would like some drag and drop so I don't waste to much time making the display part*

Comment: Your question is missing a question. In terms of IDEs: neither IronPython nor Python forces you to use any specific IDE. For alternatives to VS see for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/755901/468244).

Comment: If the tkinter (or Tkinter) module is avaliable with/for the Python you choose, I recommend [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) for simple GUI programming.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Python is the name of a programming language, there are various implementations of it:

- **CPython**: the standard Python interpreter, written in C
- **Jython**: Python interpreter for Java
- **IronPython**: Python interpreter for the .NET framework
- **PyPy**: Python interpreter written in Python

All of them are free (in the sense of not having to buy a license to use them), and can be used to create GUI programs. It really depends what you want to do and which OS you use.

There are various GUI frameworks/bindings for Python: Tkinter, PyGtk, PyQt, WinForms/WPF (IronPython) and the Java UI frameworks.

You also don't have to use Visual Studio for compiling .NET languages, there are open source alternatives like [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).

Answer (score 5):

IronPython is a implementation of Python running on .NET - however it is not the implementation that is in general referred to when someone mentions Python - that would be cPython: [Website for (normal) cPython](http://www.python.org/).

Now as to creating a UI - there are many ways that you can use to create a UI in Python.
If you only want to use what is available in a normal installation you could use the TK bindings: [TKInter](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.html). [This wiki entry](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) holds a wealth of information about getting started with TKInter.

Apart from TKInter there are bindings to many popular frameworks like QT, GTK and more (see [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) for a list).

Answer (score 1):

If cost is your concern, you can use a free version of visual studio together with PTVS: https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PTVS%20Installation

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to create a GUI that runs on Windows, C# on Visual Studio is the easiest way to go.  Their free version, Community (used to be Express) provides all the Windows controls you're used to using with a drag and drop GUI builder.

Comment: he wrote nothing about platform, even more - he were asked to do this on python. What is the sense of this answer?

Answer (score 0):

All implementations can run on Eclipse via PyDev. So it kills the argument of which one to use as it is all the same language, implementations other than this instance are more domain specific. Iron Python targets Microsoft, Jython targets Java, Python targets itself. Each environment naturally has its own complier/library all you are doing is trading environments by choosing one over the other. Each has its positives and negatives but naturally you would want to give Python a try before touching other environments as a beginners rule.