# IDE for IronPython on Windows in 2017

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, pydev, ironpython

I've developed in CPython for the past few years, and now have reason to try IronPython.

Eclipse (version 4.3) with PyDev (version 3.5) has been my favourite IDE for CPython. I tried using this combination to develop for IronPython too, but windows keep popping up stating "IronPython Console has stopped working". Does Eclipse/PyDev not support IronPython development?

I have also tried Visual Studio 2008 (only) by installing the shell integrated mode redistributable as well as IronPython Studio. However it was rather complicated for me to get it to work, with too many things to download and install.

CodePlex was another option I looked into, but their website states that they will be shut down soon.

In looking for other IDE options, I looked at this question: [IDE for ironpython on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755883/ide-for-ironpython-on-windows). However, I fear that the answers given there are outdated or will soon be outdated, because they date back to 2009.

Given all this, I am wondering: what IDEs are available in 2017 for developing against IronPython - preferably an open source IDE? In addition, is IronPython, like CodePlex, about to die?

Comment: The recent version of PyDev still supports IronPython... if you have issues, please provide details and report it at the PyDev tracker (see: http://www.pydev.org/about.html for tracker location)

Comment: Yeah, I tried it with the latest version of LiClipse (3.5) and the latest version of IronPython (2.7.7). And yes, it worked! I realised that debugging also works to some extent. I understand now that for the meantime we have to live with error messages such as "ValueError: call stack is not deep enough".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IronPython development has stagnated for quite a while, which is probably why the majority of IronPython IDE questions on Stack Overflow are from 2009 or so. However, according to the user mailing list IronPython now has [new lead developers](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/ironpython-users/2016-July/017649.html) and [plans for new work including IronPython for Python 3.x](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/ironpython-users/2016-July/017684.html)

In addition, CodePlex is only shutting down because so much has been ported to GitHub. So I would keep your eyes on the [IronPython GitHub page](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main) for updates. It looks like IronPython.net (their other official page) touts Python Tools for Visual Studio - so if you want something supported, this would probably be the way to go. Best bet would be to download [the most recent version](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases/v2.2.2) alongside VS 2015 or 2013. Given that IronPython exists to interface with .NET, I can't imagine a good reason to pick an open-source IDE over Visual Studio anyway.